# Как поменять с помощью парсера тег img

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно заменить пути к картинкам в HTML коде. Пример замены:

```
<!-- Это -->
<img alt="Sun20_opisanie_1.jpg" height="142" src="/upload/medialibrary/eca/ecaf24b68290cd575bbb1fd1d69e86f3.jpg" title="Светофильтр" width="700"/><br/>` 

<!-- Сделать таким -->
<img alt="Sun20_opisanie_1.jpg" height="142" src="/upload/ptk/img/ecaf24b68290cd575bbb1fd1d69e86f3.jpg" title="Светофильтр" width="700"/><br/>
```

То есть поменять ссылку на картинку, можете кто нибудь помочь? При этом путь к картинкам на сайте всегда разный из-за чего я даже не могу использовать команду: `replace`.

Вот сам парсер:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os


URL = 'https://evrotek.spb.ru/catalog/product/66504/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'
HOST_IMG = '/image/Aurora/'
HOST = 'https://evrotek.spb.ru'

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_Stranic(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='page-content has-leftbar cabinet catalog-card')
    stranica_svarka=[]
    image = []
    for item in items:
        stranica_svarka.append({
            "title": item.find('h1', class_='').get_text(strip=True),
            "price": item.find('div', class_='price').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True).replace(' ', '').replace('руб.', '.00').replace('\xa0', ''),
            "text": item.find('div', class_='tab-content').find_next('div'),
            "articul": item.find('div', class_='art').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True),
            'test': 'dew'
            })
    items2 = soup.find_all('div', class_='tab-pane active fade in')
    for img in items2:
        i = img.find_all('img', class_='')
        for idi in i:
            image.append(
                HOST + idi.get('src')
                )
    for i in image:
        name = i.split('/')[-1]
        with open('Картинки/' + name, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in requests.get(i):
                file.write(chunk)
    print(image)
    return stranica_svarka

html = get_html(URL)
svarka = get_Stranic(html.text)
print(svarka)
```

Полный HTML код:

```
<div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="description" itemprop="description">
<p>
Встречайте <b>новинку 2020 </b> - <b>Маска сварочная Хамелеон Aurora SUN-9 DYNAMIC</b>. Новая модель выделяется среди конкурентов и в ассортименте модельного ряда Aurora благодаря ряду преимуществ:
</p>
<p>
<img alt="Sun20_opisanie.jpg" height="128" src="/upload/medialibrary/940/9404a23a67fe322e256e483222c98a07.jpg" title="Достоинства" width="700"/><br/>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<ul>
<li>
Уникальная инновационная конструкция щитка с внутренним подъемным механизмом позволяет производить подготовительные, зачистные работы с полностью прозрачным защитным стеклом. </li>
<li>
Максимально широкий угол обзора: 150 в режиме подготовки и 120 в режиме сварки.<br/>
</li>
<li>
Технология TRUE COLOR — четкое изображение, правильная цветопередача и минимальная нагрузка на глаза сварщика. </li>
<li>
Лучший оптический класс светофильтра 1/1/1/1. </li>
</ul>
<img align="left" alt="true_color.jpg" height="154" src="/upload/medialibrary/1bb/1bbac4d6a40e3836a94dc1f3b62f0417.jpg" title="true color" width="126"/>Маска AURORA SUN-9 DYNAMIC – это сочетание технологических наработок последних лет в области производства средств защиты лица и органов зрения.  Одним из главным достоинств нового светофильтра является <b>технология TRUE COLOR</b>: инновационный подход к производству позволяет добиться высокого значения цветопередачи, гораздо более естественного и насыщенного в сравнении с обычными автоматическими фильтрами. При полном затемнении фильтра цвета не искажаются ни в зелёную, ни в фиолетовую область. При этом светофильтр Aurora также сохраняет максимальный уровень защиты от вредного синего спектра.
<p>
Установленный светофильтр обладает лучшим на сегодняшний день оптическим классом 1/1/1/1, со степенью затемнения от 3DIN. Данная маска имеет съемный элемент питания, который, при необходимости,  можно заменить самостоятельно. Также можно дооснастить щиток увеличительными стеклами. Конструкция и размеры маски позволяют использовать ее со строительной каской и респиратором. 
</p>
<p>
Светофильтр маски одинаково эффективен для всех типов сварки: MMA, MIG-MAG, TIG, TIG PULSE, а так же для сварки на малых токах TIG AC/DC от 3А (AC) и 5А при работе с DC током! 
</p>
<p>
Евро-оголовье с регулировкой в пяти плоскостях и мягким налобником, небольшой вес и сбалансированная конструкция - позволяют снизить утомляемость сварщика и обеспечить комфорт на протяжении всего рабочего дня. 
</p>
<h3>Особенности:</h3>
<ul>
<li>4 инфракрасных датчика;</li>
<li>Простая замена элемента питания - 1xCR2450;</li>
<li>Хороший обзор за счет большой площади светофильтра 100Х65мм;</li>
<li>Высший оптический класс светофильтра 1/1/1/1;</li>
<li>Комфортная сварка в режимах MMA, MIG-MAG, TIG, TIG PULSE и сварка на малых токах;</li>
<li>Солнечная батарея светофильтра;</li>
<li>Сертификат соответствия  европейскому стандарту ЕС и американскому стандарту ANSI;</li>
<li>Хорошо сбалансированная конструкция;</li>
<li>Настройка оголовья в 5 плоскостях поможет добиться оптимального расположения маски относительно лица сварщика;<br/>
</li>
<li>Возможность использования щитка с респиратором и строительной каской;</li>
<li>Запасное защитное стекло в комплекте.</li>
</ul>
<p>
Фильтр маски хамелеон срабатывает при совпадении частоты светового потока и его амплитуды. Щиток затемняется только при одновременном воздействии на датчики инфракрасных волн и колебаний высокой интенсивности. Солнце или светодиодный источник света, несмотря на свою яркость, выдают очень мягкий свет без колебаний. Светофильтр маски на подобные источники не реагирует.  Эта особенность позволяет сварщику работать под прямыми солнечными лучами не опасаясь ложных срабатываний или случайных открытий фильтра. 
</p>
<p>
<img alt="Sun20_opisanie_1.jpg" height="142" src="/upload/medialibrary/eca/ecaf24b68290cd575bbb1fd1d69e86f3.jpg" title="Светофильтр" width="700"/><br/>
</p>
<h3>Особенности фильтра:</h3>
<ul>
<li><b>2</b> режима регулировки <b>степени</b> затемнения: DIN 4-DIN 8 (для сварки на малых токах) и <b>DIN 9</b> - <b>DIN 13</b> (для стандартных сварочных задач);</li>
<li>Три варианта задержки <b>времени открытия светофильтра</b> по окончании процесса сварки от 0.2 до 1 сек.,</li>
<li>Переключатель и регулятор настройки режимов <b>сварки (DIN 4-13)</b> / <b>заточки (DIN 3)</b>;</li>
<li>Возможность задать необходимую <b>чувствительность</b> датчиков светофильтра;</li>
<li>Коэффициент проникновения УФ лучей - 0.00002%;</li>
<li>Коэффициент проникновения ИК лучей - 0.03%;</li>
<li>В светлом состоянии и в режиме "заточка" затемнение светофильтра составляет всего 3 DIN.</li>
</ul>
<h3>Регулировка наголовника: </h3>
<p>
</p>
<ul>
<li>
Изменить диаметр охвата - поворотом всего одной ручки; </li>
<li>
Выбрать комфортный угол затылочного крепления; </li>
<li>
Отрегулировать глубину посадки, переставляя пластиковые шипы в пазах; </li>
<li>
Задать необходимый угол наклона щитка и усилие для опускания/поднимания маски; </li>
<li>
Выставить комфортное расстояние от лица до светофильтра. </li>
</ul>
Маска выполнена из высококачественного негорючего и ударопрочного полиамида покрытого защитной плёнкой.  Данное покрытие, а так же обтекаемая форма маски, предотвращают прилипание сварочных брызг. 
<p>
В наличии имеются запасные стекла из поликарбоната для маски Aurora SUN-9 DYNAMIC:
</p>
<p>
<a href="https://aurora-online.ru/catalog/welding/Aksessuarii/40543/"></a>
</p>
<ul>
<li> <a href="/catalog/product/66503/" target="_blank" title="Перейти">Стекло защитное SUN-9 DYNAMIC наружное</a> </li>
<li> <a href="/catalog/product/66503/" target="_blank" title="/catalog/product/66502/">Стекло защитное SUN-9 DYNAMIC внутреннее</a> </li>
</ul> </div>, 'articul': '28397', 'test': 'dew'}]
>>>
```

Comment: То есть эту часть `/upload/medialibrary/eca/` поменять на `/upload/ptk/img/` или что? И после смены куда это девать?

Comment: Да именно эту часть нужно поменять у всех тегов img, после смены они вообще не нужны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код изменит все атрибуты `src` у изображений на `/upload/ptk/img/ecaf24b68290cd575bbb1fd1d69e86f3.jpg` или поменяете на свои ссылки. Минимальный пример кода:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://evrotek.spb.ru/catalog/product/66504/'

def get_html(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  return r.text

def replace_src(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  imgs = soup.find_all("img")
  for img in imgs:
    img['src'] = '/upload/ptk/img/ecaf24b68290cd575bbb1fd1d69e86f3.jpg'
  return soup

html = get_html(URL)
print(replace_src(html))
```

Comment: Нет это совсем не то, мне нужно выводить весь html код с измененным тегом img, и нужно поменять у всех тегов img их в моем html коде 3.

Comment: Т.е. получить html файл, и внутри файла поменять все атрибуты `src` правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, все правильно

Comment: Код обновил, попробуйте, подходит ли такой вариант.

Comment: Да так же подошел, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Выполнив следующий код после строки `svarka = get_Stranic(html.text)`, вы получите html файл, в котором все теги `img` сменят атрибуты `src` с любого начала на `/upload/ptk/img/`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(svarka[0]['text']), 'html.parser')
imgs = soup.find_all('img')
for img in imgs:
    img['src'] = '/upload/ptk/img/' + img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    soup.find('img', attrs={'src': img['src']}).replaceWith(img)

with open('page.html', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Я попробовал вставить этот код, после `svarka = get_Stranic(html.text)`, но код работает только до строки `soup.find('img', attrs={'src': img['src']}).replaceWith(img)`

Comment: Может я что-то делаю не так)))

Comment: @БогданМусихин появляется ошибка? Должен появится в файл в директории откуда запускается программа

Comment: Все работает, спасибо